# Can I start a program as a service in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have a server in windows. It isn't a service itself. Can I let it start at startup as a service in some way?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in code? If no, then the question belongs to http://SuperUser.com . In general, service is a special kind of application which interacts with the service control manager and also is usually executed under special account and within different session. Using srvany, as David Heffernan mentioned, doesn't magically turn the application into full-featured service.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [srvany](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) but be warned that it doesn't always work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to startup programs

Start > All programs > Startup programs

Just move it in this folder to let it start up with Windows.

Comment: That does *not* start it the program as a Windows Service. It just runs the program when a user logs in.

Comment: True, but with the same result. Server process is also a program indirectly.

Comment: @Cody I think @Vincent was trying to interpret the OP's underlying problem in a creative way. Maybe the question really is, "How do I get my app to run all the time in the background like a service does?"

Comment: @David: Maybe, that's why I didn't downvote. I just wanted to point out that it wasn't the same thing. My mindreading skills have never been very good.

Answer (score 0):

Srvany allows only one service at same time. So I write my srvany (sFany) to make nginx and php-cgi run as windows service together. Here is the source and binary https://github.com/stxh/sFany